# How to omit fields in a GetListItemChanges response (via request)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I have an applicatie that connects to a SharePoint webservice.
What it needs to do is determine which items are changed and stores the fields Modified, UniqueId and FileRef. To retrieve this data i use the 'Lists.GetListItemChanges'-mehod of the webservice. This gave me correct data but was really slow due to the amount of data, all fields (including the page content) were returned to me.

So after reading [Lists.GetListItemChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchanges%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN i used the ViewFields parameter with a node like `<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><FieldRef Name="UniqueId" /><FieldRef Name="FileRef" /></ViewFields>`.
The documentation said "A ViewFields element that specifies which fields to return in the query and in what order".

This did change the output by moving those fields (attributes) forward in de result-rows, but all other attributes also came back in the results, including the full content. This gives me too much overhead, how can i omit those other fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few fields that will alwys be returned. HJowever you can restrict the non-required fields like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                <listName>Team Discussion</listName>
                  <viewFields>
                    <ViewFields>
                      <FieldRef Name="DiscussionTitle"/>
                      <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
                      <FieldRef Name="MyEditor"/>
                    </ViewFields>
                  </viewFields>
                <since>2012-1-22</since>
            </GetListItemChanges>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

even so, I am not able to suppress these fields:

- ows_MetaInfo
- ows__ModerationStatus
- ows__Level
- ows_ID
- ows_UniqueId
- ows_owshiddenversion
- ows_FSObjType
- ows_Created
- ows_PermMask
- ows_FileRef

I bet the un-suppressable fields change depending on the list definition also. My example is a Discussion List